# Python read() only returns partial file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I'm working on a script that reads in a text and processes, pretty straight forward stuff I do all the time. However, this time it only reads in about 512 lines of a file that is tens of thousands of lines long. The file doesn't look truncated or anything so there must be a stray `EOF` in the file. How do I work around this? Here is a little code snippet I put together to troubleshoot this:

```
objFileIn = open(strFilein, "r")
strJson = objFileIn.read()
objFileOut = open(strFixedjason,"w")
objFileOut.write(strJson)
objFileOut.close()
objFileIn.close()
```

`strFilein` points to a json file that is 20,550 lines long. `strFixedjason` has 512 lines in it.

Comment: What happens if you try to use `.readLines()` instead of `.read()`?

Comment: Maybe your program ran out of memory?

Comment: .readlines() only reads in 512 lines. Also, I opened up the offending json file in a text editor with hex edit mode that shows me the underlying binary of the text file and there is not a single 00 (NUL) in the file. I'm working on Windows 10 if that matters. I've been able to read much bigger files in the past. In cases the script crashed with a memory error on json.loads() but it still read the whole file. So I doubt this is a memory issue.

Comment: Can you provide the file ?

Comment: Can you also try printing len(strJson) and output of objFileOut.write(strJson) ?

Answer (score 1):

OK this is totally embarrassing, turns out I wasn't feeding the script the file I thought I was processing :-(
I two files with the exact same name in two different directories, one was 512 lines the other 20K lines. I pointed the script at the smaller one and looked at the other in the editor.
You can classify this question as caused by stupid human error. :-P

Comment: Lol! You can delete the question, or leave it as a testimony to power of reducing all errors on our side before thinking something is wrong with the way built-in functions work!

Comment: *"Please close this thread"* - you are free to delete it...

Comment: I think leaving up as a warning to others to not be as dumb as I was and make sure you're not doing something dumb before you start blaming the tech. Hopefully, I learned that lesson.